# Sequelize nested conditions

Tags: sequelize.js

```
select * from courses where (days like '%a%' or days like '%b%') and (startTime <= 9  and 9  < endTime) OR (10 >= startTime and 10 <= endTime)
```

this is the sql that i want to write using sequelize

and this is what i wrote

```
const result = await models.courses.findAll({
    where: {
      [op.or]: [
        {
          days: { [op.like]: '%a%' },
        },
        {
          days: { [op.like]: '%b%' },
        },
      ],
      [op.or]: [
        {
          [op.and]: [
            {
              startTime: { [op.lte]: 9 },
            },
            {
              endTime: { [op.gte]: 9 },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          [op.and]: [
            {
              startTime: { [op.lte]: 10 },
            },
            {
              endTime: { [op.gte]: 10 },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

but result shows...

select ... from courses ...
WHERE ((`courses`.`startTime` <= 9 AND `courses`.`endTime` >= 9) OR (`courses`.`startTime` <= 10 AND `courses`.`endTime` >= 10));

What happened to my days query from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a top-level "AND" containing the days section and the starttime/endtime section.  Odd that you didn't get an error - perhaps the starttime/endtime section overlaid the days section.

---

Added later: testing confirms the 2nd clause will overlay the 1st.  e.g.

```
where : {
   [Op.or] : [{id : 1},{id : 2}],  // 1st clause
   [Op.or] : [{id : 3},{id : 4}]   // 2nd clause  
}
```

results in only

```
WHERE id = 3 OR id = 4
```

There needs to be an operand connecting the two OR clauses....

Answer (score 0):

Your current sequelize query will generate the following sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM courses
WHERE
  (days LIKE '%a%' OR days LIKE '%b%') AND
  (
    (startTime <= 9 AND endTime >= 9) OR
    (startTime <= 10 AND endTime >= 10)
  )
```

Please confirm the following is your sql:

```
SELECT * FROM courses
WHERE
  (days LIKE ‘%a%’ OR days LIKE ‘%b%’) AND
  (startTime <= 9  AND 9  < endTime) OR
  (10 >= startTime AND 10 <= endTime)
```

Then, sequelize query will be like this:

```
const result = await models.courses.findAll({
    where: {
      [op.or]: [{
        [op.or]: [{
          days: { [op.like]: '%a%' },
        }, {
          days: { [op.like]: '%b%' },
        }],
        startTime: { [op.lte]: 9 },
        endTime: { [op.gte]: 9 }
      }, {
        startTime: { [op.lte]: 10 },
        endTime: { [op.gte]: 10 }
      }]
    },
  });
```